# Get Hold of the View of an item inside RecyclerView at given position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` using `GridLayout.` Each item view consists an Image and name.

**UseCase**: On click of any item , a bottom sheet should which will have certain number of actions to do on the selected item . **One of the action is 'Rename' . On click of Rename , bottom sheet should close and TextView of that particular item should become editable**.

My Attempt : I created an Observer , which will be triggered on click of the rename action. inside this observer i am trying to get hold of the view from position .

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = mElementListView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
                if(vh == null) {
                    Log.d("AssetList","Null at position-"+position);
                } else {
                    View view = vh.itemView;
                    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.element_item_rename);
                    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException` for some of the item, even though the item clicked is visible in the list.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Can Anyone help me with this ?

Comment: please edit your question to show the layout file containing the "element_item_rename" view. Also, I'm not really sure how this code even compiles without casting the result of "findViewById" to EditText...

Comment: @GilMoshayof I am sorry but i cannot put the layout file here as it consists data of my firm. Is there any specific thing you want to know in the layout?

Comment: Well, my 1st instinct would be that this ID doesn't exist inside the itemView's layout - hence the NPE when trying to access the resulting view. Can't confirm without seeing the layout tho.

Comment: @GilMoshayof It does work sometimes. So i am hoping that ID is present in the layout

Comment: Not much I can help with without seeing more of the code / layouts. This snippet alone doesn't contain enough information to properly analyze the problem.